# Cannot count the running services with the following cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the count of all running services on my windows box. When I run:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "running" }
```

I get list of all services running. But I want to count how many of the services are running using the following command, it is showing the count as zero. That is wrong count. I have more than 20 services running on my box.

```
$acoundrunningservices = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "running"}
$acoundrunningservices.Count
```

Comment: @($acoundrunningservices).count

Comment: @iRon That would only make a difference if the OP is running PowerShell v2 or earlier and the `Get-Service` statement yields 0 or 1 result.

Comment: @Jason Can't reproduce. Please show the exact output you get when you copy/paste the second code snippet in a PowerShell console. Screenshot would be sufficient. Also, what PowerShell version are you running? Show the output of `$PSVersionTable`.

Comment: @Jason I didn't understant what you mean by "are running using the following command" - what command ? If you mean: `$acoundrunningservices = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "running"}
$acoundrunningservices.Count`   I it on my Windows box and it works fine, the count was indeed all the running services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$acoundrunningservices = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "running"}
$acoundrunningservices.Count
```

Does work for me, as well as:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "running" } | Measure-Object | Select-Object Count
```

or:

```
(Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "running" }).Count
```

Comment: My mistake was I typed lowercase .count. It should have been .Count

Comment: @Jason PowerShell is (mostly) case-insensitive, so that is definitely not the cause of your problem.